# Determine which section a Zend_Config uses in a controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-config

I have my config defined via Zend_Config_Ini adapter, with production, development and testing sections. In my controller I would like to take certain actions depending on what environment/section I am currently using - e.g. I only want to send email in production and testing, not in development.

Is there a way to determine which environment/section I am using the controller? I can set a value in the config and grab that in the controllers, but seems like there would be a cleaner way to determine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the code that depends on the environment in your controller, like this :

```
if ($env == 'production') {
    // send mail
}
```

It adds logic in the controller -- the sending of the mail doesn't depend on the configuration anymore.

I think it's better to add one `mail.enable` option in your configuration files, and use that specific option in your code, to determine whether or not you must send mails.

This way :

- The configuration is the one which defines if mails should be sent or not
- The day you want to send mails from your development environment, you just have to change one entry in your configuration file ; and not the code.

Of course, it means a couple more configuration entries *(one to enable/disable e-mails, one for any other thing that can be enabled or not)* ; but, in the end, that's what configuration is for.

Comment: If you want to use this for logging, take a look at Zend_Log. You could define the different writers in the config and that way easily change it depending on the environment.

Answer (score 2):

When you followed the ZF quick start and set up your project using the command line tool, you have a constant called APPLICATION_ENV that you can use.

E.g.

```
if(APPLICATION_ENV == "development")
{
  // custom logic here
}
```

That is getting defined in the index.php file in your public folder:

```
// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
                || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
```

Comment: Forgot about that constant, thanks, that answered my question. But, in the end, I think Pascal is right and I should just define sending mail in the config. That way, I can quickly turn sending mail on and off when developing...